# A typescript subscribe collects data from API and writes that into an array, but I can only output one of them

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am getting data from an API like this:

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.exampleDatabase = new ExampleHttpDatabase(this._httpClient);
  var href = '/schuhe-store/status';

  if (environment.production === false) {
    href = 'https://sales.dailysshop.com/schuhe-store/status';
  }

  for (var val of this.dataArray) {
    const requestUrl = `${href}?type=${val}`;

    this._httpClient
      .get<StatusInterface>(requestUrl)
      .pipe(
        map((data) => {
          return data;
        })
      )
      .subscribe(
        (data) => {
          this.dataResults[val] = data;
          console.log(this.dataResults[val]);
        },
        (error) => {
          const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();

          if (error.status == 404) {
            dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
            dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
            console.log(error.errno);
            this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, dialogConfig);
          } else if ((error.status = 200)) {
            this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, dialogConfig);
          }
          this.routeNotRegistered = true;
        }
      );
  }
}
```

In my HTML I am outputting 4 lines as follows:

```html
            <mat-list-item>
                <mat-icon mat-list-icon>done</mat-icon>
                <div mat-line>Cronjob</div>
                <div mat-line *ngIf='getTimestamp("cron"); else loading;'>Zuletzt beendet: {{ getTimestamp("cron") | date:'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm" }} Uhr</div>
            </mat-list-item>
            <mat-list-item>
                <mat-icon mat-list-icon>done</mat-icon>
                <div mat-line>Exportprozess</div>
                <div mat-line *ngIf='getTimestamp("export"); else loading;'>Zuletzt beendet: {{ getTimestamp("export") | date:"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm" }} Uhr</div>
            </mat-list-item>
            <mat-list-item>
                <mat-icon mat-list-icon>done</mat-icon>
                <div mat-line>Deltaexport</div>
                <div mat-line *ngIf='getTimestamp("delta"); else loading;'>Zuletzt beendet: {{ getTimestamp("delta") | date:"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm" }} Uhr</div>
            </mat-list-item>
            <mat-list-item>
                <mat-icon mat-list-icon>error</mat-icon>
                <div mat-line>Importprozess</div>
                <div mat-line *ngIf='getTimestamp("import"); else loading;'>Zuletzt beendet: {{ getTimestamp("import") | date:"dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm" }} Uhr</div>
            </mat-list-item>
```

The getTimestamp is the following code:

```js
    getTimestamp(key: string):number|undefined{
        if (this.dataResults[key] && this.dataResults[key]["timestamp"] !== undefined)
            return (this.dataResults[key]["timestamp"]);
        return (undefined);
    }
```

In my HTML only one value is outputted, currently, only the getTimestamp("delta") and I don't know, how to get all 4 values.

Can someone point this out and deliver a solution?

Kind regards
Henning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const dataArray = ['cron', 'import', 'export', 'delta'];


from(dataArray)
  .pipe(
concatMap((type) => {
  const requestUrl = `${href}?type=${type}`;
    return this._httpClient.get<StatusInterface>(requestUrl).pipe(map((data) => ({ [type]: data })))
  }
),
    scan((acc, curr) => ({...acc, ...curr}), {})// value will come one by one, if you want to get final result (full object) you can replace scan with reduce operator
  )
  .subscribe((data) => {
    console.log(data); // {cron: StatusInterface, import: StatusInterface, ...}
    this.dataResults = data;
  }, 
  error => {});
```

Comment: Hi @shutsman, my IDE shows an error for from(): Cannot find name "from". Anything I missed by your code?

Comment: you should imort it

Comment: import { from, of } from 'rxjs';
import { concatMap, map, scan, } from 'rxjs/operators';

Comment: added requestUrl

Answer (score 0):

Instead of subscribing to the sub observables (HTTP calls) directly, you can use `RxJS` [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin) to combine all of them, and emit the result through `subscribe` method once all the sub observables have been completed.

Try the following:

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.exampleDatabase = new ExampleHttpDatabase(this._httpClient);
  var href = '/schuhe-store/status';

  if (environment.production === false) {
    href = 'https://sales.dailysshop.com/schuhe-store/status';
  }

  if (!this.dataArray?.length) return;

  forkJoin(
    this.dataArray.map((val) => {
      const requestUrl = `${href}?type=${val}`;
      return this._httpClient.get<StatusInterface>(requestUrl).pipe(
        tap((data) => {
          this.dataResults[val] = data;
        })
      );
    })
  ).subscribe(
    () => {
      console.log('DONE!');
    },
    (error) => {
      const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();

      if (error.status == 404) {
        dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
        dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
        console.log(error.errno);
        this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, dialogConfig);
      } else if ((error.status = 200)) {
        this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, dialogConfig);
      }
      this.routeNotRegistered = true;
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi @Amer, thank you. But the val is defined by an array. it is a for(val of this.dataArray) and the dataArray is defined like this:

    dataArray = [
        "import",
        "export",
        "cron",
        "delta"
    ];

Can your code do this too?

Comment: Yes, because it's mapping the `dataArray` to an array of observables (HTTP calls), then combine all of them together in one observable using `forkJoin`. Check it please after my update.

Comment: Hi @Amer, I am getting Cannot find name 'tap'. and Parameter 'data' implicitly has an 'any' type., am I missing an import?

Comment: just import it from `import {tap} from "rxjs/operators"`